# Is it true that my 1650super runs on pcie 1.0 speed?

Tags: graphics-card, pci-express

On hwinfo, I see this

```
[Video Card]
Video Card: MSI GTX 1650 SUPER
Video Bus:  PCIe v3.0 x16 (8.0 GT/s) @ x16 (2.5 GT/s)
```

I was confused about the `2.5 GT/s` in the end, so I asked ChatGPT.

> The line "Video Bus: PCIe v3.0 x16 (8.0 GT/s) @ x16 (2.5 GT/s)" gives
> you information about the video card's potential capability and its
> current operational mode. Here's a breakdown:
>
> 1. **PCIe v3.0 x16 (8.0 GT/s):** This indicates that the video card (in this case, the MSI GTX 1650 SUPER) is designed to support PCIe
>    version 3.0 at x16 lane width with a theoretical speed of 8.0 GT/s per
>    lane.
> 2. **@ x16 (2.5 GT/s):** This means that the video card is currently operating in a x16 slot, but only at a speed of 2.5 GT/s per lane,
>    which corresponds to PCIe v1.0 speeds.
>
> ......

Is what it said true? Is it my PCIe 3.0 1650 super really running at PCIe 1.0 speed?

Comment: You could have left out all the timewasting with chatGPT and just gone to google https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-m&sca_esv=566202829&q=why+is+graphics+card+using+pcie+2.5gt-s and within 30 seconds gotten the actual answer rather than generic "check your entire PC for everything that could go wrong".

Comment: You could also have left out the ChatGPT from your question here. It is completely worthless for your question. It give no useful information or context.

Comment: @Mokubai OK. The 2nd link of the linustechtips forum does give the real answer. Thanks. Btw, there's no way I will check everything it said.

Comment: It must be addmitted that it gives some useful infomation though. Without it, I won't know `@ x16 (2.5 GT/s)` indicates the graphic card was running at pcie 1.0 speed, which lead me to ask why.

Answer (score -2):

It turns out the graphic card can adjust the speed itself, based on the workload . When playing 4K videos or 3A games, it reaches to PCIe 3.0 speed.

See also: https://linustechtips.com/topic/767927-pcie-link-speed-25-gts-gtx-980/

Comment: Why -1? Am I not giving the correct answer? Or those who -1 expect me to leave the question forever open?